# VBA Excel error "Object variable or with block variable not set" Run time error 91 & 438

Tags: excel, vba, class

I am trying to chart set of values using the following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub graphs()
Dim chart1 As Variables
Dim rlong As Single

rlong = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set chart1 = New Variables


With chart1
    .range_data = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(rlong, 1))
    .range_close = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(rlong, 2))
    .range_ema50 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(rlong, 3))
    .range_ema100 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(rlong, 4)) 'Object variable or with block variable not set. Error 91
End With

charting (chart1) 'Object doesn't support this property or method. Error 438
End Sub
```

```
Sub charting(chart1 As Variables)
Debug.Print "i am here"
End Sub
```

Here Variables is a user defined class that contains the variables i want to populate.

The run time initially gives an error at the following line

```
.range_ema100 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(rlong, 4)) 'Object variable or with block variable not set. Error 91
```

When i eliminated that line to run the code, i get another error while calling subroutine

```
charting (chart1) 'Object doesn't support this property or method. Error 438
```

Appreciate all the support...Thank you

Comment: Missing a `Set` needed for an object variable?

Comment: Are you setting the ranges inside the ```Variables``` class? for the other error remove the ```()```

Comment: Change line charting '(chart1)' to 'charting chart1'

Comment: @BigBen, you are right "Set" clears the errors. Thanks.

Comment: @Warcupine...thank you for clarification....

Comment: @JeremyHodge...thank you!